# Cant catch exception in python

Tags: python

I use `salt`, and it raise the following exception when I run `exec_state('update_salt')` (The code below):

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/client/__init__.py", line 1582, in __init__
    caller = salt.client.Caller()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/minion.py", line 283, in __init__
    for key, val in data.items():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/minion.py", line 300, in gen_modules

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/loader.py", line 286, in render
    opts,
salt.exceptions.LoaderError: The renderer yaml_jinja is unavailable, this error is often because the needed software is unavailable
```

I try to handle it by try and catch block:

```
try:
   result = exec_state('update_salt')
   if not result:
       return False
except:
   print "got it.."
   result = exec_state('update_salt_light')
   if not result:
       return False
```

But it still failed in the first attemp, and doesn't get to the exception block (got it is not printed). Why?

Comment: It's strange, that your `exec_state` call is not mentioned in the stack trace.

Comment: @oliverpool: It mentions (I attached only the end of the stack trace), but is it important for the question?

Comment: it was to be sure, that the `Exception` is really raised inside your `try: except:` block.

Comment: @oliverpool: It raised into the exec_state function

Comment: Maybe the exception is handled in `exec_state` and it then returns `None`? Have you tried `result = exec_state('update_salt') or exec_state('update_salt_light')`?